# pandas python Load JSON from local file

Tags: python, json, pandas

I'm trying to set up a github so that all the code is self contained and the other authors don't need to post their entire path to certain files.

my code:

```
dataSet = pd.read_json("file://repository/Datasets/JSON/data.json", convert_dates=False)
```

This gives me this error:

```
URLError: <urlopen error [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: '\\repository\\Datasets\\JSON\\data.json'>
```

As this is the way that the docs seem to describe how to do this, I'm stumped on how to do it

Answer (score 0):

I'd say move the file into the same directory and simply use

```py
dataSet = pd.read_json('data.json')
```

Once that works then you know for sure that it's not an issue with reading the file. The error suggests it's an issue with Windows reading the path to the file.
Not sure what editor you're using but in VS Code if you right click the file it allows you to copy the  'relative  path' in relation to the file you're currently working on.

Sorry I can't be of more help.